# IntelliJ how to change the background color of the selected file?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

I installed Monokai PRO UI in my IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 but few things I want to customize. I want to change the background color of the selected file.

[image]

How to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | File Status Colors.

Comment: In the place you pointed out, I can change the font color, but I mean the background color. I mean exactly the background color which, for example, has the "target" dir on the attached screen

Comment: It's configurable by theme only, and there may be no UI settings for that.